# Analyze the differentiability of the function $f(x,y)=|log(x-y)|$ at all points in its domain. (Check my work please)

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I got help from a past topic that I opened around here and I think I'm done. But I need help to see if my procedure is correct:

**Analyze the differentiability of the function $f(x,y)=|log(x-y)|$ at all points in its domain.**

The domain should be: \begin{align}Domf: =(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:x-y > 0 \end{align}

I can rewrite the function as follows (Thanks Eric Towers: [Analyze the differentiability of the function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4122768/analyze-the-differentiability-of-the-function/4122787?noredirect=1#comment8533624_4122787))
\begin{align*}
f(x,y) &= | \ln(x-y) |  \\
    &= \begin{cases} 
        \ln(x-y) ,&  \ln(x-y) \geq 0 \\ 
        -\ln(x-y) ,&  \ln(x-y) < 0 
    \end{cases}  \\
    &= \begin{cases} 
        \ln(x-y) ,&  x-y \geq 1 \\ 
        -\ln(x-y) ,&  0 < x-y < 1 
    \end{cases}  \text{.}
\end{align*}

Given the nature of the logarithm function, on the regions$G_1$ and $G_2$ the function is differentiable.:
\begin{align*} G_1: x-y>1\\ G_2: x-y<1 \end{align*}
The geometric place to analyze the differentiability corresponds to:
\begin{align} x-y=1 \end{align}

To study its differentiability, I will analyze the existence of partial derivatives. For this I need a point, which will be defined as follows:

\begin{align} x-y=1 \\
x=1+y\\
y=b\\
x=1+b
\end{align}

With that I get the point $(1+b,b)$:

\begin{align*} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(1+b,b) = &\lim_{h \to 0}{\frac{f(1+b+h,b)-f(1+b,b)}{h}} \\
&\lim_{h \to 0}{\frac{|1+h|}{h}} = \text{the limit does not exist}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(1+b,b)=&\lim_{h \to 0}{\frac{f(1+b.b+h+h,b)-f(1+b,b)}{h}} \\
&\lim_{h \to 0}{\frac{|1-h|}{h}} = \text{the limit does not exist}
\end{align*}

Finally, the function is not differentiable in $ x-y=1 $ since there are no partial derivatives in that place.

Any comments or help I will be very grateful!

Comment: Why have you introduced $a$?  (I'd ask the same thing about $b$, but whatever...)  You want $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(1+b,b)$.  Your version evaluates the partial derivative at points other than those with $x$ coordinate $1+b$.  The derivative you have written, with $a$, exists for infinitely many $a$.  What you have written claims the derivative does not exist for any point in the plane.

Comment: I modified everything suggested, the "a" was a typo.
How can I correctly write the point? it could be (1-y, y) (as you suggested in the previous post?)
Also "derivative does not exist for any point in the plane." is it correct or not ?

I appreciate everything, it is very difficult for me to understand this.

Comment: $f(1+b+h,b) - f(1+b,b) = |\ln(1+h)|$.  With this correction, you will be trying to evaluate the correct limits.  But why do you say the limits do not exist?  There must be some evidence for this claim.  Perhaps look at the one-sided limits and see if they agree.

Comment: I had not realized. But when I calculate the limit on the right of $\lim_{h \to 0}{\frac{|log(1+h)|}{h}}$ I get 1 and on the left -1, so the limit does not exist.

Comment: Yes.  if the two one-sided limits exist and have the same value, the two-sided limit exists.  If either one-sided limit fails to exist or if the two one-sided limits have different values, the two-sided limit fails to exist.  You have done the work to show the two one-sided limits do not agree, so the two-sided limit does not exist.